Please help me identify a post apocalyptic movie with a pregnant woman
This movie aired between 1980-2000 although it may have been made earlier. The movie starts with the explosion of an atomic bomb leaving a bright light and a massive mushroom cloud.
There is a man and (pregnant) woman surviving in a cabin. Roaming around outside are Mutant zombies. The woman gets abducted. She is practically ripped through a wall as the cabin is buried into the side of a hill. Within the hill are tunnels controlled by the mutant zombies and their leader, a man in his mid 50s.
The leader also has another pregnant woman being held captive. We learn that the mutant zombies are this way because they drink infected water infested with a parasite.
